# Transfer files to google compute engine instance in jupyter directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to transfer files from my computer (MacOS) to an instance using `gcloud compute scp`. I am trying to move the files to the `/home/jupyter` folder so I can work with them in JupyterLab. But somehow the full command `gcloud compute scp ./myPath/myFile instance-name:/home/jupyter` gives the error `Permission denied`.

Also I noticed that when navigating to this folder `~` appears. I think that means it is the actual home directory. So I tried `gcloud compute scp ./myPath/myFile instance-name:~/` which works. But now the files were transferred to `/home/username` which seems to be the real home directory.

Is there a way to navigate back?

Comment: Do you have permission to write in the directory `/home/jupyter`?

Comment: That is exactly the problem. It says I don't have. But I can't figure out why. It is my own instance.

Comment: Add your username to the same group as `/home/jupyter`. Then make sure that the group has write permission. `ls -ld /home/jupyter` will tell you the owner and group. Very basic Linux permission stuff.

Comment: @JohnHanley Would it be possible if you can apply your comment as an answer? I believe it would be beneficial to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is that you do not have permission to write to the `/home/jupyter` directory.

Step 1: Add your username to the same group as `/home/jupyter`. I will assume that the group name is `jupyter`. You can display the group name with `ls -ld /home/jupyter`.

```
sudo usermod -a -G jupyter your_user_name
```

Step 2: Make sure that the group has write permission:

```
sudo chmod g+w /home/jupyter
```

Note the above command only sets group write permission to `/home/jupyter`. If you want to add write permission to all subdirectores and files of `/home/jupyter` execute:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /home/jupyter
```